# Getting black and white image when doing rotation?

Tags: rgb, opencv, image-rotation, python

I want to rotate my image by 45 degree. I have defined a function for the same. When I run it over my RGB images, it is getting saved as grayscale images?

```
def rotateImage(image, angle):
    row,col = image.shape
    center=tuple(np.array([row,col])/2)
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center,angle,1.0)
    new_image = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, (col,row))
    return new_image


rotate_img_path = '../data/rotate_45_img'
rotate_mask_path = '../data/rotate_45_mask'
real_img_path = '../data/img'
real_mask_path = '../data/mask'


for img in os.listdir(real_img_path):
    edge_img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(real_img_path,img))
    edges = rotateImage(edge_img, 45)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(rotate_img_path, img), edges)
print("Finished Copying images")

for img in os.listdir(real_mask_path):
    edge_img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(real_mask_path,img))
    edges = rotateImage(edge_img, 45)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(rotate_mask_path, img), edges)
#     cv2.imwrite('edge_' + '.jpg', edges)
print("Finished Copying masks")
```

Answer (score 1):

A clue here may be

```
row,col = image.shape
```

which would raise an error if `image` was three dimensional (i.e., in color with separate channels for B, G, and R) instead of two (i.e., grayscale). Unless you're reading RGB images with code not shown here, this suggests that your images are already grayscale.